# JavaScript, JSP and JSON not working with POST

Tags: javascript, java, json, mongodb, jsp

I'm trying to make a client-server application where from the client I send a request through a JSON object to the server to register. The thing is I should get another JSON with an "OK" field (which is actually being sent) but for some reason the client keeps going to the `.fail` function instead of the `.done` one (sorry if some of used terms are not very accurate, I'm new to this).

So I'll this is my code incase you can check if there's anything wrong causing this:

Client JS:

```
define(['ojs/ojcore', 'knockout', 'jquery', 'appController', 'jquery', 'ojs/ojknockout', 'ojs/ojinputtext'],
 function(oj, ko, $, app) {

    function RegistrarseViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        this.email = ko.observable();
        this.pwd1 = ko.observable();
        this.pwd2 = ko.observable();
        this.registrar = function(){
            alert("Se ha mandado el registro");
            var p = {tipo:"Registrarse",email: this.email(), pwd1:this.pwd1(), pwd2:this.pwd2()};
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"http://localhost:8080/ServidorWeb/Registrarse.jsp",
                data: "p=" + JSON.stringify(p)
            }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                alert("Comprobando tipo");
                if (data.tipo == "OK"){
                    //window.location="index.html?root=juegos"
                    sessionStorage.jugador=self.email();
                    app.router.go("login");
                    alert("Registro correcto");
                }else
                    alert(respuesta.texto)
            }).fail(function()  {
                alert("Sorry. Server unavailable. lol ");
            });
        }

        this.cancelar = function(){
            app.router.go("login");
        }
    }
    return new RegistrarseViewModel();
  }
);
```

Server JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="application/json ; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import= "org.json.*,dominio.Manager"%>
<%
String p = request.getParameter("p");
JSONObject resultado=new JSONObject();
try{

 JSONObject jso= new JSONObject(p);
 if(!jso.getString("tipo").equals("Registrarse")){
  resultado.put("tipo","NOK");
  resultado.put("texto","Mensaje inesperado");
 }else{
  String email=jso.getString("email");
  String pwd1=jso.getString("pwd1");
  String pwd2=jso.getString("pwd2");
  Manager.get().registrarse(email,pwd1,pwd2);
  resultado.put("tipo","OK");
  resultado.put("texto","Te has registrado con el email " + email);
 }
}
catch(Exception e){
 resultado.put("tipo","NOK");
 resultado.put("texto","Mensaje Inesperadoo");
}
%>

<%=resultado.toString()%>
```

After executing `Manager.get().registrarse(email,pwd1,pwd2);` (which is the logic to register into a MongoDB) it just continues with the `resultado.put("tipo","OK");` line which means the problem isn't in there.

Also if I send the request `http://localhost:8080/ServidorWeb/Registrarse.jsp?p=%7Btipo:%22Registrarse%22,email:%2233%22,pwd1:%2220%22,pwd2:%2220%22%7D` from a browser like Google Chrome it prints this: `{"texto":"Te has registrado con el email 33","tipo":"OK"}` but from the real client it just won't get into the `.done` function, idk why.

I really hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1: Added the server response from the browser console** [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpTPz.png)

Comment: look in the network tab of browser console to see what's going on in the ajax request/response

Comment: it goes into a file named 'jquery3-1-1.js' and gets into an 'if (type == error)', idk why

Comment: All the network requests will be in there, you want to find the one going to registrarse.jsp

Comment: the response is '{"texto":"Te has registrado con el email joder11","tipo":"OK"}'

Comment: huh... and you get "server unavailable lol" alerted?

Comment: yes, I've edited the first post with the image from the server response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I solved this finally.

I had to add this line at the beggining of the .jsp, this was an issu with TomCat which has something like 2 machines and without this line it doesn't allow communication among different machines because of security reasons it seems.

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use jquery the correct way is use serialize function from jquery
https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

first give a id for you form something like :

`

```js
$("#myform form").submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
    
        var sendData = $("#myform form").serialize(); 
        $.post("your-PHP-handler.php", sendData);
   });
```

```html
<form id="myform" method="post" action="your-PHP-handler.php">
<input type="name" placeholder="name">
<input type="name" placeholder="age">
<input type="name" placeholder="address">
<button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

`

note when you submit your form via javascript the serialization jquery get all inputs in your post end send all together you cam handler the response php inside of $.post() you can make many things with this consulting jquery documentation.
anyway the basic is there , get everything inside my form and send to my php file

Comment: isn't that what JSON does?

Comment: yes and NO because you use jquery so you must use the jquery serialization to serialize something

Comment: and you forgot dataType: "json"

Comment: what should I serialize? "data"? could you edit it with the code please?